# mysqli_fetch_array given less than one result in loop

Tags: php

I   am   using   this  condition but it is not  working.

```
(   $sql ="SELECT * FROM testimonial where status='Active' order by date desc";
  $result= mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die ('This is the die query error'); ;
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_BOTH) )
            {             
              echo ($row['name']);

            } 
exit;)
```

Comment: are those `()` really part of your code? Define "Not working" also.

Comment: you're also using `mysqli_fetch_array()` twice here and should have been thrown an error about it.

Comment: *"die ('This is the die query error')"* - This http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php is what you should be using to get the real error.

Comment: @Fred-ii- had a chat with jay and got the error thank you for pointing that out. It becomes really difficult to write code without code editor and continuously caring for parenthesis.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure why you are enclosing this code in parentheses, but the basic approach would be to fetch only when you get ready to loop:

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM testimonial where status='Active' order by date desc";
$result= mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_BOTH) )
{             
    echo $row['name'] . '<br />';
}
```

In order to get a true error back from MySQLi you need to use `mysqli_error($conn)` which will give you the exact error coming back from the connection if there is a problem.

---

One other note - we're assuming `$conn` is properly set so if the code above does not work you'll need to share the connection code with us.

Comment: This is the answer that should be accepted. What's wrong with the OP's picture here??? *"Thanks a lot lokesh. it is working expected. – priyanka 4 mins ago"*

Answer (score 0):

```
(   $sql =mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM testimonial where status='Active' order by date desc") or die (mysqli_error($connect));
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
            {             
              echo ($row['name']);

            } 
exit;)
```